# Write List <> to the database asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

- I'm stuck writing to the database
- Don't throw me any mistakes
- Write commands do not work

**controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult>PartialTabelaEcp(string userDate)
{
     var numerMiesiaca = 1;
     var numerRoku = 1;
     var dbExists = _ecpContext.Karta.FirstOrDefault(f => f.DzMiesiaca == 1 && f.Miesiac == 
                             numerMiesiaca && f.Rok == numerRoku && f.Login == userName);
    if (dbExists == null)
    {
        List<Karta_Model> objKartaModel = new List<Karta_Model>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= liczbaDni; i++)
        {
            DateTime thisDate = new DateTime(numerRoku, numerMiesiaca, i);

            var day = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(thisDate.DayOfWeek);
            var model = new Karta_Model()
            {
                DzMiesiaca = i,
                DzTygodnia = day,
                Rozpoczecie = "00:00"
            };

            objKartaModel.Add(model);
        }

        await _ecpContext.Karta.AddRangeAsync(objKartaModel);
        await _ecpContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

return PartialView("_TabelaEwidencja" );
```

- in  _ecpContext.Karta.AddRangeAsync(objKartaModel), in objKartaModel I have a list of models, as many as 'i'

**model:**

```
public partial class Karta_Model
{
    public int? DzMiesiaca { get; set; }
    public string? DzTygodnia { get; set; }
    public string? Rozpoczecie { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: you're using async methods but not waiting for the results before moving to the next command.

Comment: @ADyson ,and how could I do this programatically?

Comment: Seems you maybe need to study some introductory async programming tutorials - both to understand what async can be used for, and also how to use it. tldr: Either make your outer method `async` and then `await` the methods, or use the synchronous versions of those methods instead. using the async/await pattern is generally advantageous in this situation because it frees up the thread in your .NET code while the database operation is executing, meaning your server has more capacity to respond to other requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is invoking `async` operations:

```
_ecpContext.Karta.AddRangeAsync(objKartaModel);
_ecpContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

So you need to await them:

```
await _ecpContext.Karta.AddRangeAsync(objKartaModel);
await _ecpContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

To do so, your method also needs to be `async`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> PartialTabelaEcp(string userDate)
```

If you don't await asynchronous operations then the code proceeds before they've been completed, so when you get to your `SaveChangesAsync` there's nothing to save.  (And that operation itself may fail and you're not observing the failure.)

Answer (score 0):

As @ADyson mentioned you're using async methods in sync code. So should either need to make your code async (as did @David or @Amankhani MohammadJavad) or make your methods sync. EF gives you both ways of `AddRange` and `SaveChanges`.

Change

```
 _ecpContext.Karta.AddRangeAsync(objKartaModel);
 _ecpContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

To

```
 _ecpContext.Karta.AddRange(objKartaModel);
 _ecpContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: ...because? Don't just dump code on someone. Explain what your change means and why it works (and any implications such as, in this case, loss of the advantages of asynchronous I/O operations.) Otherwise people who don't really understand this topic might just copy and paste your code blindly without understanding it. And you [wouldn't want that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)

Comment: You've explined :)

Comment: I've explained it partially. But still you should add it more fully to the answer body if you want to avoid downvotes...

Answer (score 0):

You are using an async method but your method is not an async method You can do this:

```
  [HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> PartialTabelaEcp(string userDate)
        {
             var numerMiesiaca = 1;
             var numerRoku = 1;
             var dbExists = _ecpContext.Karta.FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.DzMiesiaca == 1 && f.Miesiac == 
                                           numerMiesiaca && f.Rok == numerRoku && f.Login == userName);
            if (dbExists == null)
            {
                List<Karta_Model> objKartaModel = new List<Karta_Model>();

                for (int i = 1; i <= liczbaDni; i++)
                {
                    DateTime thisDate = new DateTime(numerRoku, numerMiesiaca, i);


                    var day = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(thisDate.DayOfWeek);
                    var model = new Karta_Model()
                    {
                        DzMiesiaca = i,
                        DzTygodnia = day,
                        Rozpoczecie = "00:00"
                    };

                    objKartaModel.Add(model);

                }


                await _ecpContext.Karta.AddRangeAsync(objKartaModel);
                await _ecpContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

        }
 return PartialView("_TabelaEwidencja" );
```

Comment: You forgot to await the async calls inside the method. If you don't do that then you won't fix the issue.

Comment: You can't say this is a flawed solution, it can be solved this way
Where's the problem with this?

Comment: Sorry, at the time I wrote that my page hadn't updated with your edit where you added the `await`. I have deleted my second comment now. However I do think you should also add text to the answer explaining why `await` is also a necessary part of the solution, as other answers have done.

Comment: I wanted to get the job done quickly and solve their mine
Thank you